# Get currency rates based on currency selection

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When we enter some value in text box and currency in the `fromCurrency` dropdown field and select appropriate currency in the `toCurrency` dropdown field, how do we display rates in the `toCurrency` based on that selection  ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-http-jc35u?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const axios = require("axios");
function App() {
  const [sourceCurrency, setSourceCurrency] = useState("");
  const [targetCurrency, setTargetCurrency] = useState("");
  const [ratesList, setRatesList] = useState([]);
  const [selectFromCurrency, setFromSourceCurrency] = useState("");
  const [selectToCurrency, setSelectToCurrency] = useState("");

  const getSourceCurrency = (source) => {
    setSourceCurrency(source);
  };

  const getTargetCurrency = (target) => {
    setTargetCurrency(target);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest");
        setRatesList(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const selectSourceCurrency = (sourceCurr) => {
    setFromSourceCurrency(sourceCurr);
  };

  const selectTargetCurrency = (targetCurr) => {
    setSelectToCurrency(targetCurr);
  };

  const convertRate = () => {
    const rateCalc = sourceCurrency * targetCurrency;
    console.log("print rate: " + rateCalc);
    // how can we the rates list here and based on the selection ?
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="globalCurrencyConverter">
        <h2>Currency Converter</h2>
        <div className="container box">
          <label>
            <input
              name="sourceCurrency"
              type="text"
              placeholder="fromCurrency"
              onChange={(event) => getSourceCurrency(event.target.value)}
            />
            <select
              className="fromCurrency"
              defaultValue={"DEFAULT"}
              onChange={(event) => selectSourceCurrency(event.target.value)}
            >
              <option>USD</option>
              <option value="DEFAULT">AUD</option>
              <option>NZD</option>
              <option>INR</option>
              <option>UAE Dirham</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              name="targetCurrency"
              type="text"
              placeholder="toCurrency"
              onChange={(event) => getTargetCurrency(event.target.value)}
            />
            <select
              className="toCurrency"
              onChange={(event) => selectTargetCurrency(event.target.value)}
            >
              <option>USD</option>
              <option>AUD</option>
              <option>NZD</option>
              <option>INR</option>
              <option>UAE Dirham</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <div className="recordBtn">
            <button name="convert" onClick={(event) => convertRate()}>
              Convert
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you can handle the population of those select fields with currencies yourself and instead will show you how to solve the actual conversion problem. So we shall leave those select options hardcoded as they are in your code. e.g. (USD, NZD, AUD etc.)

So we won't actually even need that useEffect for this test since we simply hardcode the currencies. Personally, I like to solve my React problems with as little re-renders as possible. So the way I would approach this specific problem is by creating references to all 4 of your fields. It will allow us to access their values any time. Check out `useRef()`.

Then when someone enters all the info and clicks that "Convert" button, I would call your API and pass it the selected currency as base currency. like so

```
https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD
```

Once axios fetches the data on it, it is just a matter of some basic match and assignment of the proper value to the "To Currency" field. So here is a working example along with a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-wood-4uzwx?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const axios = require("axios");
function App() {
  const from_select = useRef(),
    to_select = useRef(),
    from_input = useRef(),
    to_input = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest");
        //setRatesList(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const convertRate = () => {
    const from_cur = from_select.current.value;
    const to_cur = to_select.current.value;
    const from_amount = from_input.current.value;
    console.log(from_cur);
    axios
      .get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=" + from_cur)
      .then((result) => {
        const rate = result.data.rates[to_cur];
        const converted_amount = rate * from_amount;
        to_input.current.value = converted_amount;
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="globalCurrencyConverter">
        <h2>Currency Converter</h2>
        <div className="container box">
          <label>
            <input
              ref={from_input}
              name="sourceCurrency"
              type="text"
              placeholder="fromCurrency"
            />
            <select
              ref={from_select}
              className="fromCurrency"
              defaultValue={"USD"}
            >
              <option value="USD">USD</option>
              <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
              <option value="NZD">NZD</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          {" -> "}
          <label>
            <input
              ref={to_input}
              name="targetCurrency"
              type="text"
              placeholder="toCurrency"
            />

            <select ref={to_select} className="toCurrency" defaultValue="AUD">
              <option value="USD">USD</option>
              <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
              <option value="NZD">NZD</option>
              <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
              <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <div className="recordBtn">
            <button name="convert" onClick={convertRate}>
              Convert
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you. If I need to display the conversion rate first toCurrrency text field during on select of toCurrency should we  create as below: 
  ``const selectTargetCurrency = () => {
    const from_cur = from_select.current.value;
    const to_cur = to_select.current.value;
    axios
      .get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=" + from_cur)
      .then((result) => {
        const rate = result.data.rates[to_cur];
        setTargetCurrency(rate);
      });
  }``

Comment: the above is called during on change of in toCurrency select box>> onChange={(event) => selectTargetCurrency(event.target.value)}

Comment: @soccerway Pretty much. I have updated my Sandbox to reflect rates for selected currencies: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-wood-4uzwx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Awesome, I have accepted and upvoted. Appreciate your reply

Answer (score 1):

your `ratesList` would be an object extracted from `data.data.rates` with country keys and rate values set at initial `useEffect` as:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest");
        setRatesList(data.data.rates);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

your `convertRate` validates first if `sourceCurrency` is a number and if there is a `ratesList`. To calculate the conversion you need to multiply the amount value by the ratio `(toCurrency/FromCurrency)`:

```
  const convertRate = () => {
    if (isNaN(sourceCurrency) || !ratesList) return;

    setTargetCurrency(
      (ratesList[selectToCurrency] / ratesList[selectFromCurrency]) *
        sourceCurrency
    );
  };
```

set initial values for currencies:

```
  const [selectFromCurrency, setFromSourceCurrency] = useState("USD");
  const [selectToCurrency, setSelectToCurrency] = useState("NZD");
```

and remove default values for your select and input values. Instead pass the state value to have a controlled input like:

```
  <select
    className="fromCurrency"
    value={selectFromCurrency}
    onChange={(event) => selectSourceCurrency(event.target.value)}
  >
    <option>USD</option>
    <option>AUD</option>
    <option>NZD</option>
    <option>INR</option>
    <option>PLN</option>
  </select>
```

for your `toCurrency` input make it a disabled field, since you don't user to type values on it:

```
<input
  name="targetCurrency"
  value={targetCurrency}
  disabled
  type="text"
  placeholder="toCurrency"
/>
```

working demo:

[image: conversion-rate]

note: UAE Dirham doesn't match at API response so changed for PLN